# Google Cast SDK Developer Console

Tags: css, google-cast

I am currently working on a receiver app through Google Cast SDK Developer Console, and when trying to style the default receiver app created by google, through my own CSS file, in order to preview these changes it asks for a URL to my CSS, I can't figure out what exactly it's asking for in that part so I can't preview my own styles.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but answering for people looking for a solution to this question.
Question posted has as lot wrong in terms of understanding the google cast receivers.
So basically the user is trying to create a style for the styled media receiver.

---

Google cast provides 2 ready made receivers : Default and styled. You cannot do anything to the default receiver to customize it. Its just plain default receiver.
In case you want the receiver to show your logo, splash screen as well as watermark while starting the cast then you use what is known as the styled media receiver.

Now going back to the question. It is asking for a URL is because google style media receiver when invokes, needs a css input so that it can show the logo, splash screen etc. basically the UI of the receiver  which is playing the cast stream.
Why the URL? Because the URL is a direct downloadable link of the css which the style media receiver downloads and projects.

You can use your own google drive account to host the css file and provide the URL.

Refer to this link for details:
http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Building-Styled-Media-Receiver-Application-for-Chromecast